# How to use DOMDocument insertBefore

Tags: php, domdocument, appendchild, createelement

I have a div and I'm trying to insert a couple elements (h3 and p) into the div ahead of the existing h3 and p elements already living inside the div.  The PHP documentation for insertBefore (http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php) says this is exactly what should happen, but instead of inserting ahead of the existing elements, its replacing all existing elements inside my 'content' div.

Here's my code:

```
$webpage = new DOMDocument();
$webpage->loadHTMLFile("news.html");

$headerelement = $webpage->createElement('h3', $posttitle);
$pelement = $webpage->createElement('p', $bodytext);

$webpage->formatOutput = true;
$webpage->getElementById('content')->insertBefore($headerelement);
$webpage->getElementById('content')->insertBefore($pelement);

$webpage->saveHTMLFile("newpost.html");
```

I'm sure I'm just not understanding something... any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What's the code you tried using `insertBefore`?

Comment: yeah, sorry I've been interchanging insertBefore and appendChild trying to get this to work.  They do the same thing as far as I can tell.  In the above code I guess I used appendChild

Comment: just made the edit so its more clear for anyone else reading this

Comment: If you appreciate my answer, don't forget to show say thanks by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. That marks the answer as the "accepted" answer, which is for the answer you find most helpful. If a better answer comes along, you can switch it to that one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're not specifying a reference node that the inserted node should be inserted before. Think of it like this:

```
$whatTheElementIsInsertedInto->insertBefore($theElement, $whatItIsInsertedBefore)
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://codepad.viper-7.com/073L5Z)**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHtml('
  <html><head></head>
    <body>
      <div id="content">
        <h3>Original h3</h3>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
');

//find the "content" div
$content = $dom->getElementById('content');

//find the first h3 tag in "content"
$origH3 = $content->getElementsByTagName('h3')->item(0);

//create a new h3
$newH3 = $dom->createElement('h3', 'new h3!');

//insert the new h3 before the original h3 of "content"
$content->insertBefore($newH3, $origH3);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```