# insert html into source with php

Tags: php, html

I have the following html in my view source:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.****.com/en-us/snowboard">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-CN" href="https://www.****.cn/zh-cn/snowboard">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ko-KR" href="https://www.****.com/ko-kr/snowboard">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-FR" href="https://www.****.com/fr-fr/snowboard">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="it-IT" href="https://www.****.com/it-it/snowboard">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://www.****.com/es-es/snowboard">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://www.****.com/de-de/snowboard">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ja" href="https://www.****.com/ja-jp/snowboard">
```

I want to insert the follwing html tag at the top

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" href="https://www.****.com/en-gb/snowboard">
```

meaning before this tag:

```
 <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.****.com/en-us/snowboard">
```

I thought of using dom parser but it only does replacements, I just want to insert a new html element

Comment: Just add that before the other stuff in the PHP that generates that source.

Comment: Where's the PHP code you're working with? This question is unanswerable in its current form.

Comment: DOMDocument has [`insertBefore()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416277/how-to-use-domdocument-insertbefore).

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416277/how-to-use-domdocument-insertbefore?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @EdCottrell It's not really unanswerable, the answer just happens to be "okay, then do it". This doesn't require anything special, just have to add the HTML directly

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Well, OP didn't give any information about how that HTML is generated, so any *useful* answer is impossible. It seems likely to be some sort of CMS, e-commerce platform, or maybe a Wordpress plugin, in which case the answer might be somewhat involved.

Answer (score 0):

add this before your link tags...

```
<?php
    echo '<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" href="https://www.****.com/en-gb/snowboard">';
?>
```